# How to render only after a function has completed?

Tags: angularjs

I had a list of objects defined in my controller, and was sorting it after `vm.init()` like this:

```
const myItems = [{},{},{}...{}]

vm.init().then(function() {
    $scope.ajaxLoading = true;    // Loader
    $scope.itemsToRender = [];
    // Pushing items from myItems in this list according to some conditions

    $scope.itemsToRender.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.order - b.order;
    })
}).finally(function() {
    $scope.ajaxLoading = false;
});
```

This was working fine as expected,

but now I am getting `myList` from api response in `vm.init()`, and it does not sort the list when I come to this page. But if I reload the page, it sorts the list and renders perfectly.

I tried debugging and put console.log in the function, and the function was being called.

What am I doing wrong? Is the list rendering before sorting is complete? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS needs to be aware of changes in order to digest and reflect those in the template. The `sort()` method you are using is Javascript, so despite applying it directly to the $scope.itemsToRender variable Angular is still not aware its content has changed, probably because it uses properties such as length for arrays, so if the length does not change it won't recognize those changes.

Anyway I'm pretty sure you can use the `orderBy` filter instead which will handle all this for you and it's the best practise for this case

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in itemsToRender | orderBy:'id'">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy